# drone.io how to run command on local server

Tags: macos, drone.io

I have drone installed on a Mac mini as a CI/CD for Android and iOS apps. To build for iOS I need to run commands on the server itself. I know there is a ssh plugin, but is there another way to run commands on the host from a drone pipeline step?

Comment: Why do you need to run the command on the local host? The drone is based on the isolation of all stages of assembly in a virtual environment.

Comment: Obviously to build for iOS...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at the exec runner, sounds like exactly what you would need.

> The Exec runner executes build pipelines directly on the host machine without isolation, using the default shell. This runner is not suitable for un-trusted workloads for security reasons.

- https://exec-runner.docs.drone.io/

Comment: Exec runner is still in beta. Any other options?